# Convert array into simple 1 level array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

A simple thing to do, but I forgot how to convert

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hashcode] => 952316176c1266c7ef1674e790375419
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hashcode] => 5b821a14c98302ac40de3bdd77a37ceq
        )

)
```

into this:

```
Array (952316176c1266c7ef1674e790375419, 5b821a14c98302ac40de3bdd77a37ceq)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array  = array(array("test"=>"xcxccx"),array("test"=>"sdfsdfds"));

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map("array_values",$array));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xcxccx
    [1] => sdfsdfds
)
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: at risk of asking a stupid question, this seems like magic, how does it work? @Prasanth Bendra

Comment: It is like this : `array_map("array_values",$array)` this fetches all the values from inner array, and `array_merge` merges all these to a single array. Simple !!! :)

Comment: Ref: `array_map`, `array_values`, `array_merge` and `call_user_func_array` in php.net

Answer (score 5):

I know this is premature but since this is coming soon I figured I throw this out there. As of (the not yet released) PHP 5.5 you can use [`array_column()`](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-array-column-in-php-5-dot-5/):

```
 $hashcodes = array_column($array, 'hashcode');
```

Answer (score 2):

A good ol' loop solves :)

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array( 'hashcode' => 'hash' ),  
    array( 'hashcode' => 'hash2' ), 
);

$flat = array();

foreach ( $array as $arr ) {
    $flat[] = $arr['hashcode'];
}

echo "<pre>";

print_r( $flat );

?>
```

Comment: I would say that this is a more elegant way to solve this, here is a similar example http://codepad.viper-7.com/ST6fSo i just wrote.

Comment: @Ogelami I'm still seeing a multidimensional array on the link posted.

Comment: @DarylGill thats odd, i don't i didn't use <pre> tags, and i used 2 print_r's can it be that?
Here is the same code but with <pre>'s.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/g9lD5e

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = array(
    array(
        'hashcode' => '952316176c1266c7ef1674e790375419'
    ),
    array(
        'hashcode' => '5b821a14c98302ac40de3bdd77a37ceq'
    )
);

$result = array();
array_walk($source, function($element) use(&$result){
    $result[] = $element['hashcode'];
});

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
```